# power series and conditional convergence at an end point

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity, power-series

Let`s say that $f(x)$ is represented by a power series, and the series is conditionally convergent at the endpoint $x=R+C$, so is $f(x)$ continuous at that point? is it differentiable?
since we know that conditional convergence means that I can get any sum I want by rearranging the terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then $f$ is continuous at that point too; that's what [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) says. However, $f$ doesn't have to be differentiable at that point.

The fact that you can get any sum you want by rearranging the terms is not relevant here.

Comment: why is it not relevant ?

Comment: how to determine wheather f is differentiable?

Comment: @Hassan That depends upon the function.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If convergence at end point is absolute then can we say function is differentiable at end point?

Comment: @MeetPatel Yes, we can say that. It is not true, but we still can say it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I didn't get  it .**It is not true  but we still can say it**

Comment: I am saying that the statement is false. But nothing prevents us from saying false things, right?!